# Submitting dropdown information to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have broken up a many to many relationship with one holding just the primary keys of a table one called subject and one called coarse Lectures.

I have used a dropdown list from a mysql database and I just need some guidance on how to send the two dropdown options into a seperate mysql table.

```
<?php echo form_label('Lecturer :'); ?> 
<?php $sql = "select id, email from coarse_lecturers ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select email = 'sub1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo"<option value = '" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['email'] . "</option>";


}
echo "</select>";

?>


<?php echo form_label('Subject_ID :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('subjectID'); ?>        
<?php $sql = "select subject_id,subject_name  from subjects ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select subject_name = 'sub1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    echo"<option value = '" . $row['subject_id'] . "'>" . $row['subject_name'] . "</option>";

}
echo "</select>";

?>


<?php echo form_submit(array('id' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit'));?>
```

Comment: The array within the submit was just to pop the two dropdowns into an array and send them , but i found that hard to do ,

Comment: "email" and "subject_name" are not valid HTML attributes for a `select` element. I think in this case you want `name`. This is pretty basic form handling in PHP - I suggest just looking for any sort of PHP tutorial for forms and you'll see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The code written in CodeIgniter framework right? If yes then set two different object for two tables and set values.            $obj1 = new Model1();
$obj1->name = $input->post($form["name"]["field1"]);          $obj2 = new Model2();
$obj2->name = $input->post($form["name"]["field2"]);

Comment: Thanks you very much Naresh Ramoliya and Scopey ,

Comment: @NareshRamoliya any chance , could you show me what you mean with the code supplied

Answer (score 0):

Got it working ,

```
  <?php echo form_label('Lecturer  :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('dname'); ?>
<select name="lecturer">
<option value="none" selected="selected">------------Select Lecturer------------</option>

<?php $sql = "select id, email from coarse_lecturers ";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){


    echo"<option value = '" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['email'] . "</option>";




    array('id' => 'lecturer', 'value' => 'lecturer');


}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Comment: Why do you use `?> <?php` so frequently. You do not need to open and close php tags for every `echo`.